# TclOO : Use a method from another class

Tags: tcl

My goal here is to reuse a method from a class `A`, but I don't want to use all the methods of this class, just **one**.
I've tried to use these 2 functions `mixin` or/and `superclass` inside my new class `B`, but all methods from class `A` (variables and perhaps other elements I don't know about...) are also accessible on class `B`.
My question : It's possible to use just the method you want without copying them all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods don't exist except when bound to a class (or instance object, if it was created with `oo::objdefine`); the [basic C API](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Method.htm) doesn't give you a way to make a method that isn't bound (well, it does but only to support making constructors and destructors; unbound methods are in a partially-defined state). That binding is part of why *methods really aren't procedures* (though they share a lot of things).

To share a method, put it in its own class (with whatever minimal supporting declarations it needs) and mix it into the classes that want to share it. Or define a `forward`, if that makes more sense in your situation. Or just copy the definition (the result of `info class definition` is intended to be easily usable that sort of way).